# Enable Clicking Outside Bootstrap Modal when Backdrop Option is False

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using the Bootstrap modal a bit non-traditionally in that my modal is fixed to the bottom of the window, like a GDPR "accept cookies" notice.

I have also disabled the gray overlay that appears by setting the "backdrop" option to "false", per the [Bootstrap Modal Options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options), so the user can mouse-scroll outside the modal and still see their website, but **they can't click on anything on the website** because the parent modal container is full-height/full-width with a higher z-index, even though it's transparent.

Here's code illustrating the issue of not being able to click a link or interact with text while the modal is shown.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      
  $('#storyGate').modal({backdrop: false});
  $('#storyGate').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
  });  

});
```

```css
/* Story Gate Styles */
#storyGate .modal-dialog {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
}
#storyGate .modal-content {
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background: #ca2742;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade m-0" id="storyGate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="shareStoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog fixed-bottom w-100 m-0" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <p class="m-0 text-white">Have you ever eaten ice cream?</p>
          <div class="buttons d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row pr-4">
            <a href="#!yes" role="button" class="btn btn-light mr-md-2 my-2">Yes</a>
            <a href="#!no" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-light close-modal my-2 mr-0" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque</strong> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">why can't I click this</a> et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>

<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does it really need to be a modal? Why not use a `div` that is positioned below? Or what about using a [toast](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/toasts/) instead?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be a modal, but I'm curious if it's possible to allow interaction outside the modal, especially when leveraging the `backdrop: false` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of Bootstrap applying unwanted css(only in our case) on `modal` class...

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
}
```

In the above css `.modal` have `top:0;` `bottom:0;` `right:0;` `left:0;`. in this case, the modal will take `100%` `height` and `width`. so we just overwrite `top` and `left` to `auto` like below...

```
$('#storyGate').css({'top':'auto', 'left':'auto'});
```

We can solve this by css too...

```
.modal{
     top:auto !important;
     left:auto !important;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      
  $('#storyGate').modal({backdrop: false});
  $('#storyGate').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
    
  });  
$('#storyGate').css({'top':'auto', 'left':'auto'});
});
```

```css
/* Story Gate Styles */
#storyGate .modal-dialog {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
}
#storyGate .modal-content {
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background: #ca2742;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade m-0" id="storyGate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="shareStoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog fixed-bottom w-100 m-0" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <p class="m-0 text-white">Have you ever eaten ice cream?</p>
          <div class="buttons d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row pr-4">
            <a href="#!yes" role="button" class="btn btn-light mr-md-2 my-2">Yes</a>
            <a href="#!no" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-light close-modal my-2 mr-0" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque</strong> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">why can't I click this</a> et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>

<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

just your code with extra 
`.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: unset!important;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
}`

or we can say only adding `top: unset!important;` css for modal will work  `.modal {
    top: unset!important;
}`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      
  $('#storyGate').modal({backdrop: false});
  $('#storyGate').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
  });  

});
```

```css
/* Story Gate Styles */
#storyGate .modal-dialog {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
}
#storyGate .modal-content {
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
 background: #ca2742;
}


.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: unset!important;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade m-0" id="storyGate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="shareStoryLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog fixed-bottom w-100 m-0" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body p-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <p class="m-0 text-white">Have you ever eaten ice cream?</p>
          <div class="buttons d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row pr-4">
            <a href="#!yes" role="button" class="btn btn-light mr-md-2 my-2">Yes</a>
            <a href="#!no" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-light close-modal my-2 mr-0" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque</strong> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">why can't I click this</a> et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>

<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>

<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
```